# Third isomorphism theorem without normality of second subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group, K be a normal subgroup and H any subgroup such that $K \subset H$.
Is the natural map of sets:

$$ (G/K)/(H/K) \to G/H $$

still bijective?

Note: I make no assumption about finiteness of the groups involved.

Comment: Yes. It;s clearly surjective. If $g_1H=g_2H$ then $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in H$, so $g_1^{-1}g_2K \in H/K$ and hence $g_1K$ and $g_2K$ are in the same coset of $H/K$. So it is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since H is a subgroup we have the index $[G:H]$. Also since $K \subset H$ we have the index $[H:K]$. Then by the transitivity of the index we have $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$ so $[G:H]= \frac{[G:K]}{[H:K]}$ and hence $|G/H|= |G/K|/|H/K|$ even if $G/H$ doesn't have a group structure.

Comment: isn't this assuming the finiteness of the various quantities?

Comment: yes sorry, indeed if the group is not finite you can't divide $[G:K]$ by $[H:K]$. But I am pretty sure the natural map of sets is bijective.